# Request to observe environment prior to accepting job

Tags: interviewing, team, company-culture

What sort of requests are reasonable for a potential candidate who is looking to see if they would be a good fit prior to joining a company - particularly is it reasonable to request to observe a "team meeting" where more than half the team is present, or is that excessive? Aside from walking around the workplace and talking with individuals, are there any better ways to determine such a thing?

This question comes to me after [viewing this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32545/communication-environment-in-the-workplace-what-is-normal) - while I haven't had that particular issue (yet - fingers crossed/knock on wood), I feel like I have been lucky rather than diligent in avoiding it.

And since this is likely to depend on industry/culture, I am particularly interested in the US/IT perspectives, but would also like to know the differences that exist in other places.

Comment: I've read about one company (Joy, Inc.) that has a paid day-long interview (On a weekend) where you get to work with several of their employees while others observe.

Comment: @JeffO - nice to know such companies exist, but I can't imagine too many bringing in multiple employees for a full day on the weekend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a hiring manager, if I was really interested in hiring a candidate, I would have no problem letting them interact with a few selected individuals and let them ask questions in my presence or not.

However, I would not invite them to a meeting where business is discussed. Since they are not part of the company, they have not signed a Non Disclosure Agreement and therefore I would hesitate exposing them to confidential information.

This may help seal the deal in a competitive environment.

Comment: My concern is that those "selected individuals" (which are likely to be cherry-picked) are unlikely to be able to give as good an indication as an interaction where I see how decisions are made (as a team, via experience, via authority, etc.) - while you do bring up good points I was thinking about a "team meeting" where the topic is how to improve performance, adjust metrics, etc. - not something critical like business requirements or decisions. Would you be willing to discuss metrics and how they are tracked/measured, and how your team has been doing over the last X months?

Comment: In that case, if I were the candidate applying for the position, I would interview the cherry picked individuals using [behavioral interviewing](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/behavorialinterviews/a/-top-behavioral-interview-questions.htm) questions. You can get a lot of information this way.

Comment: Not quite sure how that would make the Manager feel (to have their own technique used against their team), but that probably would work quite well.

Comment: As hiring manager, quite honestly, I would find this amusing and intriguing. I would pay attention and probably ask this candidate to help me interview the next round of people as soon as they start. :-) BTW, thanks for marking as best answer!

Comment: I will point out that you can learn alot about how the team works together by just taking a tour of the office and keeping your eyes and ears open.